# how to find the excel value from row, col names in python?

Tags: python, xlsx

I am working on .xlsx using python & I am using openpyxl for the same.

I have the column name and row number. Can I find the value of that box from xlsx?

for example :

```
column - P   
row - 369
```

Can I find the value from Pth column & 369th row of xlsx ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
d = ws.cell(row = 4, column = 2)
print d.value
```

See the [documentation](http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/tutorial.html#accessing-one-cell).

Comment: The documentation also mentions you can do `ws.cell('P369')`.